# Header position offset not following top margin of container

Tags: html, css

Here I have a header with `position: fixed`. As it does not go with the normal flow of the window, a margin for the body is set to the height of the header (here 100px). Now, the body starts right after the bottom of the header.

The main div in the body has a `margin-top` of 50px. But, the header grasps that margin, and it's not shown. If I set a border on the body, then the margin is shown. I don't know what is the relation of that top margin with the border of the body.

This can be solved if I add 50px more to the margin-top of the main div. But I want to know what's happening here.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* border: 1px solid black;  */
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

main {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking... Are you wondering why applying a border to your `<main>` tag appears below the `<header>` tag (even though it is overlapped?

Comment: I set the margin-top for main to 50px. as the bg-color is white so there should be a white space of 50px between the header and the main div. But it is overlapped by the header thoough I have used the offsets properly to ensure that the body would start right after the header.

Comment: My question is why the overlapped part gets shown when I apply a border to the body

Comment: `<header>`'s height is 100px, while `<main>`'s `margin-top` is only 50px

Comment: Actually I used `margin-top: 50px` to have a gap of 50px between the header and the main div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a border adjusts the display of the layout because the `<body>` and the `<main>` margins overlap *without* the border (since it's just whitespace), but *with* the border rendered, the two margins must be separate. Thus, without the border, the total margin is 100px, and with the border, the total margin is 150px.

See demo below. (I've also added a button to hide the `<header>` since it's position is fixed, so it isn't relevant to the situation.

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const header = document.querySelector("header");

const a = document.createElement("div");
const b1 = document.createElement("button");
b1.textContent = "Toggle body border";
b1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (body.style.border !== "1px solid red") {
    body.style.border = "1px solid red";
  } else {
    body.style.border = "none";
  }
});
const b2 = document.createElement("button");
b2.textContent = "Toggle body margin";
b2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (body.style.marginTop !== "0px") {
    body.style.marginTop = "0px";
  } else {
    body.style.marginTop = "100px";
  }
});
const b3 = document.createElement("button");
b3.textContent = "Toggle header visibility";
b3.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (header.style.display !== "none") {
    header.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    header.style.display = "block";
  }
});
a.appendChild(b1);
a.appendChild(b2);
a.appendChild(b3);
a.style.position = "fixed";
a.style.top = "0";
a.style.zIndex = "2";

document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

main {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
```